# Wifi signal help at site of fibre box

Tags: internet-connection, wifi-configuration

I am somewhat less technically adept than many here so please be patient.  My question is whether I can create an access point at the site of the fiber connection by splitting the cat 5 signal that comes in and having one continue to go to the modem/ router on the other side of the house through the attic and the other stay here at the site of the outdoor fiber cable entry.  Wifi is very poor here on this side of the house where the fiber box is. If I could add something here to improve it, it would be great.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> splitting the cat 5 signal

There is no way to split it passively, you've basically three options:

- use a switch to split the cable

  - this is the closest to your approach, however it requires an extra device
  - also it won't work if you've a modem later which is required for establishing the connection
- have another cable from the router back to your AP

  - (probably that's the situation you want to avoid)
- move your modem / router to the location where you need the first split

  - this still may require an extra device to split signal later on

Comment: Thank you for your help.   I think I'll need to go the access point and additional cable route success I think it needs the modem to establish the connection as you've said.  The setup would be an unmanaged PoE switch at the modem/ router and then an AP in the room where the signal is needed running a CAT5 between the two.    https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00BP0SSAS/ref=cm_sw_r_apa_i_KBNXEbCB3YW7T  and then https://www.amazon.com/dp/B015PRCBBI/ref=cm_sw_r_apa_i_7DNXEbB0MGQAK .   Does that seem to make sense?

Comment: Still looking to resolve this. Any help is appreciated.